# Problem Installing MVC 2 RC2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010

System is Windows 7 32 bit fully up2date, Visual Studio 2008 & 2010 RC.
Trying to install AspNetMVC2_RC2_VS2008.exe following the instructions from http://haacked.com/archive/2010/02/10/installing-asp-net-mvc-2-rc-2-on-visual-studio.aspx I keep getting this error

Prerequisite check for system component Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 2 - Visual Studio 2008 Tools failed with the following error message:
"The .NET Framework version 3.5 SP1 is required. You can install the .NET Framework from the Microsoft Web site. Please install a compatible version of the Framework and try installing this release again."

See the setup log file located at 'C:\Users\ME\AppData\Local\Temp\VSDCFD8.tmp\install.log' for more information.

Relevant info from the log file as follows..

```
Result of running operator 'ValueNotExists' on property 'ValidVS2008SKU': false
Result of running operator 'ValueNotEqualTo' on property 'AdminUser' and value 'True': false
Result of running operator 'ValueLessThan' on property 'Framework35SP1' and value '1': true
Result of checks for command 'MvcToolsVS2008\VS2008ToolsMVC2.msi' is 'Fail'
'Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 2 - Visual Studio 2008 Tools' RunCheck result: Fail
A prerequisite failed for Package "Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 2 - Visual Studio 2008 Tools"
```

I definitely have .NET 3.5 SP1 installed and up2date...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running the installer as administrator by right clicking the installer file and selecting "Run as administrator".

Comment: Thanks for the reponse  çağdaş, but I am already a local administrator and UAC is turned down to minimum..

Comment: @Alex DeLarge : In that case, maybe you should try going to "Turn Windows features on and off" and then turning off .NET 3.5.1 and on again. Some on http://forums.asp.net/t/1511209.aspx says it has solved the issue (which is similar to yours) for them.

Comment: Yes, I actually did that this morning and it sorted it for me.

Thanks for your help!!!